# Random Permutation Poisson proof

Tags: probability, permutations

Let $F$ be the number of fixed points of a random permutation on $n$ items. Show that as $n$ approaches infinity, the distribution of $F$ approaches a Poisson distribution with a mean $(\lambda)=1$.

Comment: In fact $F$ and the Poisson distribution have the same moments up to and including the $n$'th.  See e.g. http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/browse_thread/thread/a617036892cf4889/22f6dcf1706a3ebb?

Answer (score 0):

To construct a permutation of $n$ objects with $k$ fixed points, we can choose the fixed points in $\binom nk$ ways and then choose a derangement for the remaining $n-k$ points. The fraction of permutations of $n$ objects that are derangements goes to $\mathrm e^{-1}$ as $n\to\infty$, so the number of permutations of $n$ objects with $k$ fixed points is asymptotically

$$
\binom nk\mathrm e^{-1}(n-k)!=n!\frac{\mathrm e^{-1}}{k!}\;.
$$

Since there are $n!$ permutations overall, the probability that a uniformly randomly chosen one has $k$ fixed points goes to $\frac{\mathrm e^{-1}}{k!}$, which is the probability for a Poisson random variable with mean $1$ to take the value $k$.